# Excel connection between chart and slicer

Tags: excel, charts

In Excel 2010 I created my first dashboard, that consisted of pivot chart and slicer to it, that I moved from the sheet with the pivot table. I checked all the connections. Everything worked fine. I saved file, reopened it several time. And without any reason chart stopped responding to the slicer.
 I deleted slicer, added it again, it worked. But again after a few reopening of the file, it stopped working again. 
I tried logically understand what I was doing wrong, but couldn't find.
I will be very grateful if you can help me with this issue.
Thank you!

Comment: That's a very quirky behavior indeed. I don't know what might be going on, but I do have a couple thoughts on a work-around. First, is it possible to leave the slicer, chart, and pivot on the same sheet? If not, you may want to try feeding the chart indirectly, by having a set of formulas that mirrors the values in the pivot table. Be sure to MANUALLY type the cell references, if you click the target cell you'll get the formula behind that part of the pivot table (which won't update with the table/slicer).